# Turn off sorting of modified files in Project Explorer in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse's Project Explorer tries to be smart and sort modified files at the beginning of the folder. This is extremely annoying for large projects with tens or hundreds of files. Anyone knows a way to turn this feature off?

Comment: The sorting in plain Eclipse Oxygen's  _Project Explorer_ is primary folder before files and secondary alphabetical. Which version do you use and which plug-ins do you have installed?

Comment: I am using Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers which has EGit plugin. Perhaps it's commit from the plugin...

Comment: In the view menu of the _Project Explorer_ choose _Filters and Customization..._: Which extensions to show are selected in the _Content_ tab?

Comment: @howlger checked: Synchronize Elements (twice), Working sets, Fortran Elements, Build Targets, C/C++ Elements, TMF Elements, Resources.  unchecked: Nexted projects

Comment: I guess it is one of these extensions. Could you uncheck them one by one to find which is responsible for the sorting?

Comment: you were right, i turned off **both** `Synchronize Elements` and the sorting goes away! Thank you!

Comment: Great, I added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Project Explorer* the default sorting/ordering is primary folder before files and secondary alphabetical. Obviously, the chronological sorting comes from an *Project Explorer* extension. To **disable the unwanted *Project Explorer* extension** do the following:

1. In *Project Explorer*'s **view menu** choose ***Filters and Customization...***
2. In the ***Content*** tab of the *Filters and Customization* dialog **uncheck** unwanted extensions to show, in your case probably ***Synchronize Elements***

Comment: Running Eclipse Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0). This solution doesn't work any more. "Synchronize Elements" no longer under "Content". 
Any other solution?

Comment: @BernieP In the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers there was never "Synchronize Elements". In this specific case here , "Synchronize Elements" was from a plugin that the questioner installed. If you don't have "Synchronize elements", that's a different issue for which you please better ask a separate question with more information (what additional plugins do you have installed; a screenshot of what you see with a description of what you expect instead; etc.).